# What's the difficulty in finding instantaneous velocity?

Tags: calculus, soft-question

I'm reading Stewart's *Essential Calculus*:

> **EXAMPLE 1** Suppose that a ball is dropped from the upper observation deck of the CN Tower in Toronto, 450 m above the ground.
>   Find the velocity of the ball after 5 seconds.
>
> **SOLUTION** Through experiments carried out four centuries ago, Galileo discovered that the distance fallen by any freely falling body
>   is proportional to the square of the time it has been falling. (This
>   model for free fall neglects air resistance.) If the distance fallen
>   after seconds is denoted by and measured in meters, then Galileo’s law
>   is expressed by the equation
>
> $$s(t)= 4.9t^2$$
>
> The **difficulty** in finding the velocity after 5 s is that we are
>   dealing with a single instant of time $(t=5)$ , so no time interval is
>   involved. However, we can approximate the desired quantity by
>   computing the average velocity over the brief time interval of a tenth
>   of a second from $t=5$ to $t=5.1$:

What he meant with **difficulty** here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He means that whereas it's easy to define the average velocity over a period (as displacement divided by time), it's much harder to define instantaneous velocity.  So instead of thinking initially about an instantaneous velocity, he considers the average velocity over a very short period of time.

Answer (score 5):

**Average velocity** has clear physical content: it is change in displacement divided by elapsed time.  **Instantaneous** velocity is more of a theoretical construct: there is no clear way that such a thing could be measured.

Comment: Isn't instantaneous velocity just $v_{avg}=\frac{\Delta d}{\Delta t}=\frac{d_f-d_i}{t_f-t_i}$?

Comment: That fraction only makes sense if $t_f\neq t_i$, but that means that you're not looking at an instant.

Comment: It may be a very dumb question, but why can't we just $t$ for $5$ in $s(t)= 4.9t^2$?

Comment: Here, $s(t)$ stands for displacement (that is, the distance fallen), not velocity or speed.